# If $a \mid b$, then $n^a \mid n^b$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n, a, b$ be integers such that $a \mid b$. Does it follow that $n^a \mid n^b$ for any integer $n$?
I believe it does and here is what I have tried. From $ a \mid b$ we have that $a \mid a-b$. Now, $\frac{n^a} {n^b} =n^{a-b} $ and here I am stuck.

Comment: Can we assume that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers ? Then, the proof of the statement is quite easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a\mid b$ holds and $b\ne 0$ , then there is a positive integer $k$ with $b=ak$ , hence $$n^b=n^{ak}=(n^a)^k$$ implying $n^a\mid n^b$

Comment: And even that $n^b$ is a power of $n^a$.

Comment: @Bernard Do you agree that $b\ne 0$ is necessary ?

Comment: Yes. For me the hypothesis is that $n, a, b$ are all positive integers, anyway.

Answer (score 11):

More simply, if $a\le b$, then $n^a$ divides $n^b$. And if $a\mid b$, $\;a\le b$.

Answer (score 4):

If $a$ and $b$ are *positive* integers, then $a \le b$ then $n^a\mid n^b$, for any positive integer $n$. If we also have the stronger relation $a | b$ [if $a$ and $b$ are still both positive that is] then not only does $n^a|n^b$, but what also holds is the stronger relation that $n^b$ is actually an *integral power* of $n^a$.

[If $b=0$ then $n^b$ is still a power of $n^a$ namely the 0-th power, but $n^a  \nmid n^b$. So it is crucial that $a$ and $b$ be positive integers.]

Answer (score 0):

So $b=ax$ , that plus $ax=\underbrace{a+\cdots+a}_{\text{x times}}$ 
, and $n^a\cdot n^a=n^{a+a}$ is enough. Just repeatedly use the last one and you'll eventually get a, added x times. This makes the exponent b. n,a, and b should all be positive integers though.